# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'edit'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made a simple slash command for my discord bot using python, to show bot latency. However, it does not appear to be working. can you help me out? thanks a lot :D.

My code:

```
import time
import discord
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents.default()
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
tree = app_commands.CommandTree(client)

prefix = "-"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix,intents=intents)
 

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    await tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=ID))
    print("Ready!")

 
@tree.command(name = "ping", description = "test command", guild=discord.Object(id=ID)) 
async def ping(Interaction):
    before = time.monotonic()
    message = await Interaction.response.send_message("pong")
    ping = (time.monotonic() - before) * 1000
    await message.edit(content=f"pong `{int(ping)}ms`") <-- here's the line that's causing the problem..  

client.run('TOKEN')
```

I've been trying to find the issue on the Internet, and I haven't been able to find it. D:
I tried to fix it myself somehow, but I am new to coding with python and was not successful.

Comment: Don't auto sync, and don't make API calls in on_ready. Why do you have bot a `Client` and a `Bot` that you're not using? What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U cannot store the interaction like `message = await Interaction.response.send_message("pong")` and update it.
You can edit the interaction by using `edit_original_message()`

```
@tree.command(name = "ping", description = "test command", guild=discord.Object(id=ID)) 
async def ping(Interaction):
    before = time.monotonic()
    await Interaction.response.send_message("pong")
    ping = (time.monotonic() - before) * 1000
    await Interaction.edit_original_message(content=f"pong `{int(ping)}ms`")
```

Comment: Hey Conner! I appreciate you answering my question.

I tried your code and it solved my initial issue. However now I am getting: 'Interaction' object has no attribute 'edit_original_message' error. 
Are there some possible solutions or am I doing something wrong?
Many thanks!

Comment: Try adding ``await Interaction.response.defer()``  right below ping() function, I normally use nextcord so i am not sure if it may work on discord.py but u can give it a try.

Comment: Figured it out! I just needed to replace `Interaction.edit_original_message` with `Interaction.edit_original_response`. Thank you for your assistance Conner! (Also, I apologize for such a late response.)